# Too loud headset

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, audio, pulse-audio

I have creative 720 headset and they are too loud on Windows 7 and Linux Mint 17.1. Adjusting volume to 1% in control panel of win7 is not enough, they are still loud. On linux pulseaudio minimum loudness is 34 % (loud enough), if I set lower then 34 % - headset will be absolutely silent. By the way pavucontrol shows that this USB headset use analog output, which is strange, cause they have their own Digital-to-analog converter. How to make them quiter in both systems?

Official site doesn't contain any driver.

Comment: Does it have a volume controller on the headphone or the wire itself?

Comment: @Bas Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I make them quieter?

Use the inline volume control.

**Note**

- One customer review reports "volume control is faulty". See below.
- A workaround is to install http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/ to an audio device and adjust the device's master volume.

---

#### Intuitive in-line controls

> Making adjustments is a breeze with the convenient in-line volume and
> microphone mute controls that also incorporate a light indicator to
> show the microphone mode status.
>
> [image]

Source [ChatMax HS-720](http://en.europe.creative.com/p/headphones-headsets/chatmax-hs-720)

---

#### Volume control is faulty?

> Con: I can not set the volume to a sensibly low volume! Although the
> volume control on the computer *would* allow much lower settings, the
> little amplifier in the USB plug just shuts off after 1 second if I go
> below a certain level (at least I think that's what happens) . That
> threshold is way too high, it is just bearable, but uncomfortably loud
> to listen to music for longer.
>
> Your mileage may vary. If you're half-deaf already and want to use it
> for gaming at a loud LAN-party or so, this might be for you.

Source [Creative ChatMax HS-720 Headset](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Creative-51EF0410AA002-ChatMax-HS-720-Headset/dp/B004AM7E30)

---

#### Workaround using EqualizerAPO

> I recently got a USB headset (Creative ChatMax HS-720 for the record),
> and I've been having a problem where my computer thinks it's a set of
> speakers, and as a result, the volume is extremely loud and only the
> minimum setting is bearable. The volume control on the headset doesn't
> help because it only adjusts the volume of my computer (already at
> minimum).
>
> ...
>
> I found a fix. http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/
>
> You can install this program to an audio device and adjust the
> device's master volume.

Source [Problems with a USB headset in Windows 7](http://neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=593326)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Real great workaround. For those who are interested edit
C:\Program Files\EqualizerAPO\config\config.txt
add line Preamp: -17 dB
Note: the same headset in different USB ports are different headset for Windows. Also before editing check your headsets in C:\Program Files\EqualizerAPO\Configurator.exe